# Secure password transfer from stdout to another window

Tags: encryption, linux, password-management, keyloggers, python

I am currently trying to build a little, secure password manager. As of now, I've implemented the encryption. Each website has its own file and each file has a number of fields (Most commonly username and password).
I am using serpent 256 to encrypt the files, and I use a random key (created Crypto.Random in python) that is encrypted using GPG, with a 4k key.
Side question: The key is sha256 hashed in order to be able to enter whatever size you want ('cause sha256 always has 256 bit result), do I lose any entropy/security/etc.?

My main question, is how can I securely transfer the decrypted data from my program to, let's say a browser text field or a terminal.
I am concerned about keyloggers.
So, clipboard is out, virtual typing is out.

I don't know what to google, so search term suggestions are welcome too.
I am working on linux (I don't care about other OSes) with python.

The code so far: http://git.dzervas.gr/panman

Comment: You hash 4k-bit key to 256-bit, and then use that as the key?

Comment: No, I use gpg with a 4k key to decrypt a random 256-bit key and then I hash it.

Comment: You use a random x-bit key, which you hash to 256-bit, and then use that? If x > 256, then yes, you lose entropy, if it's < 256, then you don't gain entropy. It seems a lose-lose situation.

Comment: I'm confuse about your security model: what do you want to protect against with such a system and what do you want to achieve that existing solution cannot do?

Comment: @domen the key has to be exactly 256 bit. I use hashing to be able to use bigger passwords.

Comment: @Stephane It's a password manager. I want to protect my passwords against reading while I'm offline (cracking the files I use to store my passwords). Also I want to protect against attacks while I transfer my password from the password manager to the application I want to use it (browser field) via a keylogger or something like that

Comment: @ttouch Once you have a keylogger on the system, it's basically game over already because you have hostile code running in the context of the user that has access to your passwords. The logger will easily snap it directly off the browser's edit field.

Comment: @ttouch Also, you didn't explain what you expected to achieve that isn't already implemented by existing solutions.

Comment: I just wanted to do it on my own...